# Disk warning 51 on Windows 2008 x64 Standard R1

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, hard-drive, performance

I keep getting a disk warning 51 message in the system log every few months. It eventually causes the server to crash (killing all my network services), forcing me to do a hard reboot.

Full error (repeats until the server is rebooted):

An error was detected on device \device\harddisk0\dr0 during a paging operation.

I also get (error 6):
An I/O operation initiated by the Registry failed unrecoverably. The Registry could not flush hive: '\??\c:\users\someuser\ntuser.dat'.

I'm running some network/disk intensive applications: one is visual studio 2005 mvc application that collects a data feed, writes some of it to a log file and forwards the whole feed, via a socket, to a java application.

The java 6  application also writes most of the data to a log and some of it to a mysql 5.1 database. I have java 6 update 20 (gonna try updating this).

I know this is a lot of redundant data, but I like to have it around for debugging purposes.

I'm thinking that the network buffers are getting overloaded. This is a Dell Poweredge R710   with a broadcom netxtreme II bcm5709c nic. May try getting another card.

In the past I tried installing the latest windows updates and updating my Dell SAS 6/iR controller driver.

Anyone have an issue like this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it looks like a hard drive may be failing. How are the disk drives set up on this machine?

Comment: That was my initial suspicion, but this server is pretty new (only had a year and a half) and the first time I got this error was 3 months after it was installed. Ran dell diagnostics on disk and checked out ok. I only have one drive, which is partitioned into a system and data section. The drive has write caching enabled.

Comment: A] make a backup now if you haven't already just to be safe
B] do you have a way to check the SMART data coming from the drive?

Comment: I'm in the process of installing open manage on there. I know in the past some dell set ups I worked on gave the smart status in the windows event log. I will see about getting a smart tool on there. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: The 5709 chips had an updated firmware released last Dec that fixed *a lot* of problems; be sure you've updated since then. What kind of RAID, HBA, disk subsystems, etc are you using? Are they updated and have all the management software installed? Any reports in the management software? Are you using officially supported Disks in the server?

Comment: Chris, I think your suggestion solved the problem. I updated the firmware (I was reluctant to do at first this since I don't have physical access to the server and didn't want to lose my network connection). Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris' suggestion did the trick.

I updated the firmware for broadcom netxtreme II bcm5709c nic (I was reluctant to do at first this since I don't have physical access to the server and didn't want to lose my network connection).

We haven't had any crashes since then.

Answer (score 1):

Not to repeat Lamam B but I have done this recently.

Do a backup, ShadowProtect Server is great if you want to mirror the whole thing and drop it onto a new hard disk for minimal down time. I did it a couple of months ago and was back online within 2 hours.

I am sure there is alternatives out there but SP is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing backups sporadically. Now I have an automated backup, that copies stuff to the cloud, in case anything happens.